# Git travando no windows

Tags: windows, git

Ola, sou iniciante no uso do git, instalei o mesmo uma primeira vez e ele funcionou normalmente, mas queria fazer algumas alterações e não conseguia, resolvi desinstalar e instalar novamente, não funcionou corretamente mais, ja desinstalei e instalei muitas vezes, mas ele não funcionou corretamente.

Ao passar ao mouse pelo gitbash ou git GUI ele trava, ao tentar movimentar a barra de rolagem do gitbash com o mouse ele trava, quando trava tenho que fechar a janela com o mouse e confirmar na janela do windows o fechar.

Estou tentando e lendo tutoriais a 3 dias, não sei mais o que posso fazer, sera que alguem consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Já fizeste "reiniciar" ao windows? qual a versão do windows?

Comment: Qual versão do Windows você está usando? Qual versão do Git você instalou? Como você instalou (baixou o instalador, fez via Chocolatey)?

Answer (score 1):

Veja no Painel de controle > Programs > Uninstall a program, se o Git não está instalado. Se estiver remova.

No Windows eu sempre faço a instalação via Chocolatey, é como o instalador de pacotes do Debian (apt-get).

Para isso acesse https://chocolatey.org/install, você encontrará diversas maneiras de instalar, e por instalação leia-se executar uma linha de comando.

Após é só chamar *choco* no console, powershell ou não, e o comando install. Você também pode pesquisar **choco list [o que você quer instalar]**.

Use:

> *choco list git.install*

O *git.install* tem todas as dependências necessárias para instalar o Git no Windows.

Para instalar:

> *choco install git.install -y*

ou

> *cinst git.install -y*

O argumento -y já faz o aceite da permissão de execução do script de instalação.

Em seguida para testar é só digitar *git* no console. Abra outra sessão do console para ele recarregar as variáveis de ambiente que tem o path para o git.
Se não der certo remova usando *choco uninstall -f*, a chave -f é para forçar a desinstalação.